# .net core 3.1 with react - render navmenu items based on identity role

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am new to react and i'm trying to display or not display nav menu items based on the current user's role.
What is the correct way to do something like this in NavMenu.js (@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))):

```
render() {
    return (
        <header>
            <Navbar className="navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" light>
                <Container>                        
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
                    <Collapse className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                            @if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                            {
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/">Home</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            }                                
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/counter">Counter</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/fetch-data">Fetch data</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <LoginMenu>
                            </LoginMenu>
                        </ul>
                    </Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </header>
    );
}
```

is it possible to use the built in AuthorizeService.js in the ClientApp/src/components/api-authorization directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you need to configure your IdentityServer to add roles info into token.Then you could get roles in React `user.Profile`.Finally, display content based on roles using 
trinocular expression

1.Create a custom `ProfileService` class in asp.net core end.

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> mUserManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        mUserManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await mUserManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        IList<string> roles = await mUserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

        IList<Claim> roleClaims = new List<Claim>();
        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            roleClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        context.IssuedClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
        //Add more claims as you need
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

2.Register in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()     
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        services.AddIdentityServer()
             .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }
```

3.Modify your `NavMenu.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Container, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarToggler, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LoginMenu } from './api-authorization/LoginMenu';
import './NavMenu.css';
import authService from './api-authorization/AuthorizeService';

export class NavMenu extends Component {
  static displayName = NavMenu.name;

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        collapsed: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        role: null
      };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._subscription = authService.subscribe(() => this.populateState());
        this.populateState();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        authService.unsubscribe(this._subscription);
    }
    async populateState() {
        const [isAuthenticated, user] = await Promise.all([authService.isAuthenticated(), authService.getUser()])
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated,
            role: user && user.role
        });
    }
      toggleNavbar () {
        this.setState({
          collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
        });
      }

    render() {
        const role = this.state.role;
        return (
          <header>
            <Navbar className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" light>
              <Container>
                <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to="/">ReactCore31</NavbarBrand>
                <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
                <Collapse className="d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
                    <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
                        {
                            role && role.includes("Admin") ?
                                <span>
                                    <NavItem>
                                        <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                                    </NavItem>
                                </span>
                                : null}
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/counter">Counter</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/fetch-data">Fetch data</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                        <LoginMenu>
                        </LoginMenu>

                      </ul>
                </Collapse>
              </Container>
            </Navbar>
          </header>
        );
    }
}
```

4.`AuthorizeService.js`(without changes)

```
async isAuthenticated() {
    const user = await this.getUser();
    return !!user;
}
async getUser() {
    if (this._user && this._user.profile) {
        return this._user.profile;
    }

    await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();
    const user = await this.userManager.getUser();
    return user && user.profile;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the complete solution!  Works great!  TY